# if $P\Rightarrow Q$ Then both are banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

$X,Y$ are norm linear space and $T_n$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators from $X\to Y$ consider the two statements below

$P:\{\|T_n(x)\|\}$ is bounded for ever $n$

$Q:\{\|T_n\|\}$ is bounded for every $n$

which of the following statements is correct?

1. if $P\Rightarrow Q$ Then both are banach space
2. if $P\Rightarrow Q$ Then one of them is banach space
3. If $X$ is a banach space then  $P\Rightarrow Q$
4. if $Y$ is a  banach space then  $P\Rightarrow Q$

I am completely lost. could anyone help me to solve?or neccessary information which will help me to solve?

Comment: Does $n$ depend on $x$ for the property $P$? Or the same $n$ works for all $x$? If $n$ doesn't depend on $x$ then $T_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the previous comment. I should have said "Does the bound depend on $x$ for the property $P$? Or the same bound works for all $x$? If it not depends, then $T_n=0$ for all $n$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1)$ and $2)$ take non-complete normed spaces, take any non-zero linear bounded operator $T:X\to Y$. To get a counterexample set $T_n=T$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Statement $3)$ is correct by uniform boundedness principle.

For $4)$ see [this counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99987/what-facts-about-the-weak-topology-fail-in-spaces-that-arent-banach/100277#100277).