# Given a Banach space $X$, are weak$^*$ bounded subsets of the dual space $X '$ also strongly bounded (with respect to the usual norm in $X '$)?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Some related facts I already know:

1) In a Banach space $X$, weakly bounded sets are strongly bounded and vice-versa (Thm 3.18 - "*Functional Analysis*", Rudin);

2) From 1, it follows that my question is equivalent to proving that weak$^*$ bounded sets are bounded with respect to the weak topology of the dual $X'$.

3) If X is reflexive, then 2 is easy to show and then my question is true. But reflexiveness is really necessary?

Comment: Perhaps this would be also inteeresting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99987/what-facts-about-the-weak-topology-fail-in-spaces-that-arent-banach

Answer (score 3):

Reflexivity is not necessary. Since $X$ is a Banach space, the Banach-Steinhaus theorem asserts that a family of continuous linear functionals on $X$ that is pointwise bounded (weak* bounded) is equicontinuous (norm-bounded).

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure that weak* bounded implies that the family of linear functionals is pointwise bounded. I can only control their bound on a finite number of points of X, not all of them!

Comment: The definition of pointwise bounded is "for each $x\in X$, there is a $K_x$ such that $\lvert \lambda(x)\rvert \leqslant K_x$ for all $\lambda\in M$". You only consider finitely many points at once [namely one single point at a time].

Comment: Sure! Now I see! Thanks!! :)